# Chat Bot para Whatsapp/

Tags: python

necesito un bot para whatsapp pero que no trabaje desde whatsapp web, estoy probando este https://github.com/mnkgrover08/whatsapp_automation que esta muy bueno, pero tendria que mandar 1 mensaje a varios contactos y no tiene esa opcion.Solo tiene mensaje de difusion pero la otra persona tiene que tener registrado mi numero si o si.

**este es el codigo del menssage simple.py**

```
import requests
import json
from configs.readconfig import configp
import logging
import pika
import uuid
import unittest
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import sys, logging, json, re, os
from workers.whatsapp_single_message_worker import WhatsAppSingleMessage,ParametrizedTestCase

class Rabbit:

    def __init__(self):
        rhost = configp.get('rabbitmq', 'ip')
        username = configp.get('rabbitmq', 'username')
        password = configp.get('rabbitmq', 'password')
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username, password)
        parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(rhost,5672,'/',credentials)

        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)

        self.channel = self.connection.channel()

        result = self.channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)

        self.callback_queue = result.method.queue

    def msgproducer(self,queuename,message, emulatername, action):
    # Get the service resource
        try:
            routingkey = queuename+".*"
            exchange = queuename+".exchange"

            self.response = None
            self.corr_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

            res = self.channel.basic_publish(exchange=exchange,
                      routing_key=routingkey,
                      body=message,properties = pika.BasicProperties(reply_to = self.callback_queue,
                                             correlation_id = self.corr_id,headers={'emulator_name':emulatername, 'action': action}))

            if res:
                self.connection.close()
                return self.corr_id

            else:
                self.connection.close()
                return False
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            return False


    def msgworker(self, queuename):
        while 1:
            self.channel.basic_consume(self.callback, queue=queuename, no_ack=True)
            print "Waiting For Messages"
            self.channel.start_consuming()

    def callback(self,ch, method, properties, body):
        print body
        print properties
        if properties.headers['action'] == 'send_only':
            print type(body)
            body = eval(body)
            print body
            #body = json.loads(body)
            emulator_name = body['emulator_name']
            mobile_number = body['mobile_number']
            message_body = body['message_body']
            print message_body
            try:
                print "entered"
                #obj = WhatsAppSingleMessage().var_setup(emulator_name,mobile_number,message_body)
                suite = unittest.TestSuite()
                suite.addTest(ParametrizedTestCase.parametrize(WhatsAppSingleMessage, emulator_name=emulator_name,mobile_number=mobile_number,message_body=message_body))
                #suite.addTest(ParametrizedTestCase.parametrize(TestOne, param=13))
                result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
                # unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
                print "de-entetred"
            except Exception as e:
                print e

        elif properties.headers['action'] == 'create_and_send':
            print "Not handled"
        else:
            print "default handle"


        print(" [x] Received %r" % body)

    def main(self):

        global LOGGER

        FORMAT = '%(levelname)s: %(asctime)-15s: %(filename)s: %(funcName)s: %(module)s: %(message)s'
        logging.basicConfig(filename="/var/log/whatsapp_single_worker.log", level=logging.DEBUG, format=FORMAT)
        LOGGER = logging.getLogger("single_worker")
        single_message_queue_name = configp.get('queue_name', 'single_message')
        try:
            self.msgworker(single_message_queue_name)
        except Exception as e:
            LOGGER.error(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rabbitInstance = Rabbit()
    rabbitInstance.main()


****este es del worker****

    import os
import unittest
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import json
import sys
import re
import MySQLdb
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


class ParametrizedTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """ TestCase classes that want to be parametrized should
        inherit from this class.
    """
    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest', emulator_name= None,mobile_number=None,message_body=None):
        super(ParametrizedTestCase, self).__init__(methodName)
        self.emulator_name = emulator_name
        self.mobile_number = mobile_number
        self.message_body = message_body

    @staticmethod
    def parametrize(testcase_klass, emulator_name= None,mobile_number=None,message_body=None):
        """ Create a suite containing all tests taken from the given
            subclass, passing them the parameter 'param'.
        """
        testloader = unittest.TestLoader()
        testnames = testloader.getTestCaseNames(testcase_klass)
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        for name in testnames:
            suite.addTest(testcase_klass(name, emulator_name= emulator_name,mobile_number=mobile_number,message_body=message_body))
        return suite

class WhatsAppSingleMessage(ParametrizedTestCase):
    "Class to run tests against the WhatsApp app"
    #def setUp(self):
    def setUp(self):
        "Setup for the test"
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '9'
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'emulator-5554'
        # Returns abs path relative to this file and not cwd
        # desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'apps/whatsapp.apk'))
        desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.whatsapp'
        desired_caps['appActivity'] = '.Main'
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
        self.emulator_name = self.emulator_name
        self.mobile_number = self.mobile_number
        self.message_body = self.message_body
        # self.action = action

    def check_exists_by_xpath(self,xpath):
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False
        return True

    def check_exists_by_class_name(self,class_name):
        try:
            self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name(class_name)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False
        return True


    def tearDown(self):
        "Tear down the test"
        self.driver.quit()


    def runTest(self):
        self.test_single_mode()

    def test_single_mode(self):
        print "entered into whatsapp"
        final_whatsapp_message_broadcasted = self.message_body
        sleep(2)
        initiate_chat_button_xpath  = '//android.widget.ImageView[contains(@content-desc,"New chat") and contains(@resource-id,"fab")]'
        initiate_chat_button_xpath_status = self.check_exists_by_xpath(initiate_chat_button_xpath)
        if initiate_chat_button_xpath_status:
            initiate_chat_button_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(initiate_chat_button_xpath)
            initiate_chat_button_element.click()
            sleep(2)
            search_contact_xpath = '//android.widget.TextView[contains(@resource-id,"menuitem_search") and contains(@content-desc,"Search")]'
            search_contact_xpath_status = self.check_exists_by_xpath(search_contact_xpath)
            if search_contact_xpath_status:
                search_contact_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(search_contact_xpath)
                search_contact_element.click()
                sleep(2)
                search_text_box_xpath = '//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,"search_src_text")]'
                search_text_box_xpath_status = self.check_exists_by_xpath(search_text_box_xpath)
                if search_text_box_xpath_status:
                    search_text_box_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(search_text_box_xpath)
                    search_text_box_element.click()
                    sleep(2)
                    search_text_box_element.send_keys(self.mobile_number)
                    sleep(2)
                    mobile_number = self.mobile_number
                    element_selected_chat_xpath = '//android.widget.TextView[contains(@resource-id,"contactpicker_row_name") and contains(@text,"{mobile_number}")]'.format(**locals())
                    element_selected_chat_xpath_status = self.check_exists_by_xpath(element_selected_chat_xpath)
                    if element_selected_chat_xpath_status:
                        element_selected_chat_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_selected_chat_xpath)
                        element_selected_chat_element.click()
                        sleep(3)
                        message_body_xpath = '//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,"entry") and contains(@text,"Type a message")]'
                        message_body_xpath_status = self.check_exists_by_xpath(message_body_xpath)
                        if message_body_xpath_status:
                            message_body_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(message_body_xpath)
                            message_body_element.click()
                            sleep(3)
                            message_body_element.send_keys(self.message_body)
                            send_element_xpath = '//android.widget.ImageButton[contains(@resource-id,"send") and contains(@content-desc,"Send")]'
                            send_element_status = self.check_exists_by_xpath(send_element_xpath)
                            if send_element_status:
                                send_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(send_element_xpath)
                                send_element.click()
                                print "broadcast sent successfully"
                            else:
                                print " send element Not Found"
                            self.driver.back()
                            sleep(2)
                        else:
                            print "Message Body Element not found"
                    else:
                        print "Element chat selector not found"
                else:
                    print "search text box for typing not found"
            else:
                print "Search contact button icon not found"
        else:
            print "New Chat Icon/button not found"



#---START OF SCRIPT
#if __name__ == '__main__':
    #suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(WhatsAppSingleMessage(emulator_name,mobile_number,message_body))
    #unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

por favor necesito que el mensaje simple lo envie a varios contactos.
o si saben de algun otro bot que este bueno y whatsapp no lo bloquee

Comment: Mandar el mismo mensaje a varios contactos es por definición SPAM, ya que su significado es realmente algo que produces en masa, que no está personalizado, y que por lo mismo pierde relevancia, cualquier sistema anti SPAM debería de ser capaz de al detectar una nueva cadena bloquearla ( y la forma más fácil es bloquear mensajes repetidos ).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y comentario

Comment: Cómo te fue con el proyecto en que estás?, te han respondido que es SPAM, pero hay ocasiones en que obligadamente se debe hacer uso de enviar un mismo mensaje a varios destinatarios, como por ejemplo en el ciclo de facturación de un servicio recurrente, hay que avisar a todos los subscriptores que se ha generado una nueva factura, a fecha de vencimiento enviar un mensaje a todos los que no han pagado avisando que su factura está próxima a vencerse, y así con todos los anuncios masivos a personas que comparten el mismo estado de la factura.

Comment: La verdad que la función de enviar mensajes por WhatsApp es muy necesaria para algunos sistemas, alguno de ustedes pudo ver algo sobre el tema?

Comment: puedes configurar el bot para que envíe cadenas de máximo 80 mensajes y no te bloquean por Spam. Es como he estado trabajando y hasta ahora no ha pasado nada.